# How should I pass login data from client to server using REST API

Tags: rest, authentication, login, client-server

I want to create a new session, the new session will be created by logging in (naturally).

Should I pass the username and password:

- via URL (`POST` request to `session?username=:username&password=:password`)
- or should I use a header instead (for instance - `Authorization`?)?

I want to stress that the session is not existent, I want to create it.

Comment: Are you using a session to store persistent state information, or just for authentication?  I think it's a good idea to avoid the notion of "sessions" in a restful API, and just pass authentication parameters by header.

Comment: @Matthew: So I should pass username and password to the server every time I make a request? I was actually thinking about obtaining a session token from the server when logging in, which would be passed every time a request was made. Is this a bad approach? If yes, why?

Comment: It's bad because it makes it more difficult for the client (they must make an extra call and save state [the token] on their end), and you have to deal with session expiry scenarios on both ends.  Stateless restful services are easier to test and understand.  I would just pass the authentication information on every call.  I do it through headers, I tend to use "basic http authentication", it's a very simple mechanism.

Comment: @Matthew : Thank you. So here's the deal :) : You write it as an answer and I accept it. What do you say?  :)

Comment: Show me the money!

Comment: @Matthew: You got your money! Enjoy! And once again - thanks for giving me the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend keeping your RESTful interface stateless.  This means for every request, you must pass in all authentication information.  I have used [Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) (credential in HTTP headers) with great success.

Keeping your RESTful interface stateless greatly simplifies your server logic and your client's logic.  Every request is autonomous, and you do not have a [temporal coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29#Object-oriented_programming) on your authentication mechanism.  It makes your application easier to test, and you will not run into scenarios where the session expires and the client doesn't expect it.